# Javascript / Node.js importing html file and passing parameters to html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodemailer

I'm making a node.js server which sends emails on demand. I'm importing an html file, which I assign to "output". This is then emailed to the receiver.

```
app.post("/send", (req, res) => {
    console.log("sending email...");
    const token = req.body.data.token;
    const output = fs.readFileSync('emailcontents.html').toString();
```

This works. But what would be the best way to pass the "token" variable to emailcontents.html?

Comment: When you build an endpoint where the html file can grab this?

Comment: @Alex What do you mean?

Comment: wait I will do an answer but I'm not sure if it is the best way

Comment: how to you import the html file and how you send the email out?

Comment: @SJ19 I updated my answer, and ejs work in any case unless you don't want to install ejs package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I misunderstand your requirement, please let me know. I'll do my best to modify the answer.

According to the conversation in comments, we  could know you want to send a email to the user instead of using `res.render` to render `emailcontents.html` content for user in browser.
That email should contain the `token`.
And you want to insert `token` into your `emailcontents.html` instead appending.

We assume your html content look like this.

```
<h1>weclome here</h1>
<p> Please use this token to do something</p>.
```

You want to insert token into {here}.

```
<h1>weclome here</h1>
<p> Please use this {here} to do something</p>.
```

instead of {here}.

```
<h1>weclome here</h1>
<p> Please use this token to do something</p>. {here}
```

According above the requirement, I come up with two options.

### First one, use `replace` method.

Before use this method, you need to modify your html like this.

```html
<h1> this is emailcontents.html content</h1>
<h1>{token}</h1>
```

Then use replace method to replace `{token}`.

```js
app.post("/send", (req, res) => {
    console.log("sending email...");
    const token = req.body.data.token;
    fs.readFile('emailcontents.html', (err, data) => {
        const output = data.toString().replace("{token}", token)
        // do other send mail job
    })
```

**Note: you could use `replace` only when your html is very very very simple.**

If your html is this, it's more complicated to handle it.
In this situation, I'll recommend you use second solution.

```html
<h1>weclome here</h1>
<h1>{token}: {token}</h1>
```

### Second, use template engine

You could use template engine to pass parameter, such as [ejs](https://ejs.co/).
It could work in any case.

```
<!-- emailcontents.ejs -->
<h1>this is emailcontents.html content</h1>
<h1>Please use this <%= token %> to do something</h1>
```

```js
const ejs = require("ejs")
app.post("/send", (req, res) => {
    console.log("sending email...");
    const token = req.body.data.token;
    ejs.renderFile("./emailcontents.ejs", {token: token}, (error, output) => {
        // output is html string with token which you provide
        // do send mail job
    })
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225935/discussion-on-answer-by-jack-yu-javascript-node-js-importing-html-file-and-pas).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I accepted your answer.

Comment: "Note: you could use replace only when your html is very very very simple." What do you mean with very very very simple?

Comment: @SJ19 I have an example in my answer. You could image what if your html is `<h1>{token}: {token}</h1>`, but you wanna replace second {token}? Maybe you could add symbol with `+` into `<h1>{token}: +{token}</h1>`, and use `replace("+{token}", token)`. But, every time you changed your html, you might change your string in your `replace(string, token)` method. It depend on the html content you wanted. You also could image what if you want to replace multiple `{token}`. That's why I said you could simply use `replace` method only when your html content is simple without situation I mentioned.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you